# ChefDK : chef shell-init SHELL_NAME command

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Maybe I'm going crazy, but in the README for ChefDK is says

(https://github.com/opscode/chef-dk#chef-shell-init)

> chef shell-init
>
> chef shell-init SHELL_NAME emits shell commands that modify your environment to make ChefDK your primary ruby. For more information to help you decide if this is desirable and instructions, see "Using ChefDK as Your Primary Development Environment" below.

So I tried:

```
eval "$(chef shell-init zsh)"
```

and

```
eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"
```

All I get is.

```
Unknown command `shell-init'.
```

The help returns the following:

> Available Commands:

```
verify    Test the embedded ChefDK applications
gem       Runs the `gem` command in context of the embedded ruby
generate  Generate a new app, cookbook, or component
```

So is the README out of data, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you build chef-dk yourself or install it from a downloaded package?

The [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/opscode/chef-dk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) shows that shell-init has just been introduced in version 0.2.0, which is not available on the [download page](http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk) yet.

You can check what version you have with `chef -v`

Comment: That seems correct - ChefDK 0.2.0 should be officially announced "[today](https://github.com/opscode/chef-community-irc-meetings/blob/master/2014-07-11-minutes.md#notes)" (= 3 days ago). So expect it to happen soon.

Comment: Now it's available on the download page :-)